# How to Solve : Flutter App Crashes while picking image from camera using image_picker plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am getting image from user choice, image choosing from gallery is working fine but using camera (ImageSource.camera) is not working. app exited automatically, advise me to solve this crash.
plungin [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker).

Sample Code:

```
Future<Null> _pickImage() async {
    try {
      final image = await _picker.getImage(
        source: (imageSource == 1 || imageSource == null)
            ? ImageSource.gallery
            : ImageSource.camera,
        imageQuality: 100,
      );    
      
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.code);
    }
  }
```

> Error:   I/Timeline(26952): Timeline: Activity_launch_request
> time:824458537   V/FA      (26952): Recording user engagement, ms:
> 292433   V/FA      (26952): Connecting to remote service   V/FA
> (26952): Activity paused, time: 2477947042   V/FA      (26952):
> Connection attempt already in progress   D/FA      (26952): Connected
> to remote service   V/FA      (26952): Processing queued up service
> tasks: 2   D/FA      (26952): Application going to the background
> Lost connection to device.   Exited (sigterm)

Comment: are you using an emulator or an actual phone?

Comment: am using real mobile

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i just added these two permissions in ../main/AndroidManifest.xml that solved the issues.

Make sure to write these code.

Comment: after clean and running, its not working again it exited if i open camera in mobile